# push origin HEAD error

Tags: git, github

Le hice un `git clone` a un repositorio alojado en github:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/USUARIO/REPOSITORIO.git
```

Luego le hice un `git fetch --all` para pasarme a la rama `dev`:

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git checkout dev
```

Para cerciorarme de que estuviera en `dev`:

```
$ git branch
*dev
master
```

Ahora bien, mi problema es que quiero trabajar dicho repositorio con un usuario en específico para lo cual ejecuté:

```
$ git config user.email MI_USUARIO_ESPECIFICO@ejemplo.com
$ git config user.name MI_USUARIO_ESPECIFICO
```

Revisé el archivo local de configuración de `git` el cual me devolvió correctamente:

```
$ cat .git/config
[user]
    email = MI_USUARIO_ESPECIFICO@ejemplo.com
    name = MI_USUARIO_ESPECIFICO
```

Añadí un archivo al proyecto:

```
$ git add assets/js/dependencies/jquery.min.js
```

Le hice su respectivo commit la cual hizo correctamente:

```
$ git commit -m "Dependencia jQuery añadida"
```

Procedí a hacer su `push origin HEAD`

```
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Y me devolvió este error:

```
remote: Permission to USUARIO/REPO.git denied to MI_USUARIO_GLOBAL.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/USUARIO/REPO.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

> ¿No debería pedirme las credenciales del USUARIO_ESPECIFICO?
>
> ¿A qué se debe este error y cómo puedo corregirlo?

**NOTA**

> Estoy seguro que el repositorio existe y el USUARIO_ESPECIFICO ya tiene permisos en el mismo

Comment: No se si te puede solucionar porque no estoy seguro , pero has probado `git push origin dev` , ya que te mueves de `branch` y el push es mejor hacerlo en el propio dev y luego hacer un merge. Yo personalmente nunca hago un push al head, sino al proyecto  en si , ya que supongo que si lo hago al proyecto main del repositorio , actualizaré el puntero que apunte el head.

Comment: Quizás esté relacionado con esto: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-to-user-repo-denied-to-user-other-repo/

Comment: @CodeNoob yo había probado eso y me saltó el mismo error, yo recurro al `git push origin HEAD` porque en la documentación dicen que si ya haz cambiado de rama (como lo muestro arriba) el `git push origin HEAD` apuntará a la rama que esté seleccionada por defecto

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, si estas utilizando una distribucion linux, solo necesitas ejecutar el comando:

```
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Con permisos de usuario, por ejemplo si usas ubuntu o alguno basado en el:

```
$ sudo git push origin HEAD
```

me ha pasado, y creo que ese es el problema, Saludos! :)

Comment: Estoy en `windows` desde una consola de administrador

Answer (score 1):

El problema puede ser el protocolo, prueba lo siguiente, edita `.git/config` y dentro de la sección `[remote "origin"]` busca lo siguiente:

```
url=https://github.com/USUARIO/REPO.git
```

Y cambia `http` por `ssh` o `git`, así:

```
url=ssh://github.com/USUARIO/REPO.git
```

o

```
url = git@github.com/USUARIO/REPO.git
```

Si el problema es el protocolo, eso debería solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que comienzas haciendo un clon del repositorio:

```
git clone https://github.com/USUARIO/REPOSITORIO.git
```

ese repositorio pertenece al usuario cuyo nombre aparece en la url, ("USUARIO" en este caso).

Posteriores `push` intentarán hacerlo sobre ese mismo repositorio, por lo que te pedirá las credenciales del "USUARIO" que figura en esa ruta.

El que hayas especificado mediante `git config user.email` y `git config user.name` unos datos, no cambia para nada que la URL del repositorio remoto al que harás PUSH pertenece a otro usuario. Los datos especificados mediante `git config` sólo sirven para identificar a quién hace los *commit* (de modo que si el "USUARIO" del repositorio lo compartiera contigo y te diera permisos para hacer push, cuando hagas esos push aparecerán con tu nombre en vez del suyo, pues varios programadores pueden colaborar en un mismo repositorio).

Asumo que no es el caso en que "USUARIO" pueda darte permisos para acceder a su repositorio. Por tanto lo que tienes que hacer es:

- Desde Github ingresar con tu propio "USUARIO_ESPECIFICO".
- Con la sesión iniciada en Github usar el navegador web para ir a `https://github.com/USUARIO/REPOSITORIO`
- Pulsar el botón "fork".
- Esto creará una copia de ese repositorio, pero en tu cuenta, es decir, hará aparecer el repositorio `https://github.com/USUARIO_ESPECIFICO/REPOSITORIO`

A partir de aquí, en tu máquina de desarrollo harás un clon de tu copia:

```
git clone https://github.com/USUARIO_ESPECIFICO/REPOSITORIO.git
```

El resto sería como planteas en tu pregunta. En el momento de hacer push te pedirá las credenciales de `USUARIO_ESPECIFICO` porque ese es el propietario del repositorio clonado.

### Bonus

Por cierto que los cambios que subas a github mediante `push` irán lógicamente a tu copia del repositorio (tu *fork*) sin afectar a lo que hubiera en el repositorio original `https://github.com/USUARIO/REPOSITORIO`.

Si quieres que tus cambios se integren en ese otro repositorio, ya que no tienes permisos para hacerlo, debes pedirlo a su propietario que sea él quien los integre. Para eso existen los llamados "Pull requests". El propietario original recibirá un "Pull request" en el que podrá ver qué cambios has hecho en tu *fork* y decidir si aceptarlos e integrarlos en el suyo.

Este es el modelo de colaboración en proyectos de código abierto.